# sublime text 3 on mac os not keeping project open

Tags: mac, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm using sublime text 3 on mac.  Whenever I've had a project or folder open and closed the window (not quit the app)  it would remember where i last left off, and open my last window.  I noticed now when I close the window it gives me a blank document.  I have to go browse to open the project.  Is there some setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't have a set of project folders automatically open after closing and reopening the Sublime Text window (this has something to do with OS X memory management). However, if you have a lot of folders to open, instead of dragging them one by one into the Sublime Text window, you can do the following (which saves lots of time).

1. Open Sublime Text and add folders by either dragging them into the window or opening them by going to `Project > Add Folder to Project`. They should appear in the sidebar.
2. Go to `Project > Save Project As...` and choose a directory to store your project information.
3. You can then `Project > Edit Project` or `Project > Refresh Folders` if needed.
4. The next time you close and reopen your window, you can quickly re-add all your projects/folders by going to `Project > Recent Project` and clicking on the only available project.

Although this way doesn't open the projects *automatically* for you, you can get back up and running **in one or two clicks.**

Answer (score 5):

Follow this guide here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753743/sublime-text-3-on-mac-os-not-keeping-project-open

The main thing here is to close Sublime after adding the project folder (properly close it) by select Sublime and Quit.

This should then remember your folders, without having to specifically save them as a project

Comment: The most simple and working answer. Not sure why no votes for this.

Comment: Best awnser. Perfect.

Comment: Indeed the best solution. Saving workspaces and projects manually and having to open then on startup is not convenient. I wish I could vote twice for this answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Sublime Text, and work normally.
2. Go to "Project" > "Save Workspace As..." and choose a directory to store your workspace information.
3. The next time when you open Sublime Text. If it's not keeping everything you opened, Go to "Project" > "Open Recent" and choose the workspace you saved last time.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

> when I close the window it gives me a blank document

This is intentional.

Command-Q - Quit the app. Quitting ST will retain open files in all open windows (the workspace) in last-saved state. Your quit 'project' will re-open when you restart the Quit Sublime Text.

Command-W (or click window 'x') to remove from workspace (includes all open tabs in window).

> Is there some setting I'm missing?

File › Open Recent, if you need to re-open files recently closed. Shift-Command-T to reopen last file closed.

'Soft-dumping' of workspace content that you describe is intentional. Open Recent, Close and Quit - 3 commands work together to provide what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use [RedQuits](http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html), which quits app when closing last window